# Prolog domain restriction

Tags: prolog, sudoku, clpfd

How can one tell Prolog/CLPFD to only use certain number of domain only as last resource?

E.g. : domain from 0...8. I want Prolog to use 0 only if there's no other option. I used the 'down' option for labeling, but too many 0's are assigned.

Context: Hoo-Doo game -> Generate 8x8 board solution where any column,row or diagonal have the numbers from 1-8 without repeating (Sudoku like). One must use two transparent pieces (represented by 0, which can be anywhere) in order to complete the solution.

Here's the code:

```
...

setDomain(H,BoardSize), 
maplist(all_distinct,H), 
IndexI is BoardSize - 1, 
IndexJ is BoardSize - 2,
checkDiagonalsLR(H,IndexI,IndexJ,BoardSize), %calls the all_distinct
IndexJ2 is BoardSize - 1,
checkDiagonalsRL(H,1,IndexJ2,BoardSize), %calls the all_distinct
transpose(H,Columns), maplist(all_distinct,Columns), 
useLabeling(Columns,BoardSize), printBoard(Columns).

useLabeling([],N).
useLabeling([H|T],N) :- labeling([down],H), useLabeling(T,N).
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use Boolean variables `Bs` and reified constraints so that `B_i` is 1 iff `V_i` is zero:

`(V_i #= 0) #<==> B_i`

the sum of the `B_i` variables is then the number `N` of zeroes that occur in your solution:

`sum(Bs, #=, N)`

Then, you can use `labeling/2` in such a way that `N` is minimal:

`labeling([min(N)], Vs)`

This works (with small adjustments) for example in SICStus and SWI.

Comment: How could that work in my code? I'm using SICStus. I'm new to Prolog, sorry about that

Comment: As you need exactly 2 zeros, there is no need to minimize.  You can have a sum constraint like `sum(Bs,#=,2)` and leave the labeling as it was.

Comment: Actually is not exactly 2 zeros. It should only use 0 if no other option is available in order to complete to board, so there can be 0,1 or 2 zeros (maximum 2). This happens because the size of the board is variable, I just used 8x8 as an example (which has a 2-zero solution)